# If gold could be multiplied, what value does it have?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

When Harry, Ron and Hermione break into Gringotts, they discover that all the gold in the Lestrange's vault can be multiplied by touch. The gold in the vault later triples and begins to overflow the vault. If one can simply multiply anything they have, wouldn't gold lose its value? Hermione also uses the Gemino charm on the locket, to make Umbridge think she still has the authentic one, proving that the copy can be easily confused, and anyone can just sell it to get money.

Answer (score 1):

The charm can be easily dispelled by a counter-spell.  Furthermore, the objects would degrade more rapidly than the original.

Hermione could fool Umbridge because they didn't need the locket to last a long time, and also because Umbridge didn't do anything with the locket except use it to bolster her claims.

Comment: Can you add a source for this?